# Внедрение ресурса в EXE

Tags: delphi, exe, ресурсы

Хочу внедрить музыку в EXE и проиграть. Файл ресурса music.res изготовил через
MYWAVE RCDATA LOADONCALL 2.wav
и поместил в каталог с исходником.

```
{$R music.res}
procedure RetrieveMyWave;
var
  hResource : THandle;
  pData     : Pointer;
begin
  hResource:=LoadResource( hInstance, FindResource(hInstance, 'MYWAVE', RT_RCDATA));
  try
    pData := LockResource(hResource);
    if pData = nil then raise Exception.Create('!!! MyWave');

    PlaySound('MyWave', 0, SND_NODEFAULT);
  finally
    FreeResource(hResource);
  end;
end;
```

Вызывая процедуру, ничего не слышу.

---

Воспользовался таким вариантом
procedure RetrieveMyWave;
var
  hResource : THandle;
  pData     : Pointer;
  KK:bool;
begin
     MMSystem.PlaySound(
  LockResource(
    LoadResource(HInstance, FindResource(HInstance, 'MYWAVE', 'wave'))
  ), 0, SND_ASYNC or SND_MEMORY );
end;

при ресурсе
MYWAVE wave "D:\mywave.wav" (другой формат+кавычки)

звук есть.
Всем спасибо.

Comment: вот тут PlaySound('MyWave', 0, SND_NODEFAULT); второй параметр неверен

PlaySound('MyWave', pData , SND_NODEFAULT); pData- необходимо привести к требуемому типу

Comment: Всё правильно, только уточню:
"Параметр hmod используется только при параметре fdwSound равном SND_RESOURCE. В этом случае hmod является дескриптором выполняемого файла, содержащего ресурс, который должен загружаться. В противном случае значение hmod задается равным 0."